# How to do sequential mean of a table in r

Tags: r, mean

Hi I am a beginner in R so my apologies for my question.
I am trying to do a table that would be a list of the means each 50 rows of another table of values.

For now my code is :

```
library(dplyr)

library(groupdata2)


a <- read.csv2(file.choose())

View(a)

a<- group(a,n=50,method="greedy")

View(a)

a$number<-as.numeric(a$number)

View(a$number)

b<-  a%>% group_by(.groups) %>% summarize(mean_size=mean(number,na.rm=TRUE))

View(b)

write.csv2(b,file="chr50.csv")
```

It works fort attributing a group each 50 rows but for a reason I ignore (b) let just only a table of one value

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example with the expected output? You can `dput()` the data structure you are working on or a toy example

Comment: 67L, 667L, 1102L, 1009L, 302L, 
459L, 83L, 294L, 359L, 791L, 368L, 766L, 2171L, 2029L, 2821L, 
447L, 123L, 5364L, 1144L, 2900L, 12687L, 238L, 1964L, 1510L, 
1277L, 148L, 1971L, 666L, 416L, 1515L, 2172L, 435L, 3463L, 1473L, 
2940L, 1290L, 644L, 5770L, 1706L, 1484L, 26L, 5267L, 1139L, 1884L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -127257L))
Is this what you asked ? This is the initial table that is working for converting values into HTML and puting color on the cell depending on the value.I think that if I have the same format of table with the means each 50 rows It should be working.

Comment: The argument `i` is not used in the function `function(i) {mean(event:(event+50))}`